# How can i make my placeholder show on datepicker input?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, placeholder

I have a `react-datepicker` component inside my form and i am trying to put a placeholder which says "please select a date" but datepicker only shows the date.I did research and some people say placeholder shows only if `selected={...}`  is false but i don't know how to make my `selected={}` false on default and show on toggle.

I tried to use react-datepicker's code,it is `placeholderText=""` but i couldn't implemented it

this is my state in my form;

```
bookTime: {
          data: new Date(),
          name: "bookTime",
          category: "text",
          everFocused: false,
          isValid: true,         
          extra : {
            label:"Randevu Tarihi*",
            help: "Geçersiz Alan!"
          }
       },
```

this is my datepicker component;

```
<DatePicker className="turkish"
                  locale={tr}
                  placeholderText="Please select a date"
                  onChange={this.handleChangeDatePicker}
                  onChangeRaw={this.handleDateChangeRaw}
                  selected={bookTime.data }

                  showTimeSelect
                  minTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 7)}
                  maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 22)}
                  minDate={subDays(new Date(), 0)}

                  timeFormat="HH:mm"
                  timeIntervals={60}
                  dateFormat="HH:mm,d MMMM yyyy"
                  timeCaption="Saat"

                />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are setting the current date as the **bookTime.date** at the initialization. So the selected value will not be empty at the start.

Try setting bookTime.date value to **false at the initialization**. Whenever a new date is picked, it (this.handleChangeDatePicker) should update the date.

Comment: sorry i am a beginner i know how to make a state false but i don't know how to make value to false at the initialization :(

Comment: just replace data: new Date() with data: false

Answer (score 11):

```js
placeholderText={'Please select a date'}
```

It work!